# file_get_contents() breaking ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: php, html, http, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am trying to read a page using file_get_contents() but I cannot get the character encoding to work.

this is my code:

```
    $username = "masked";
    $password = "maskedPass";
    $remote_url = 'https://utfws.utfpr.edu.br/aluno01/sistema/mplistahorario.inicio?p_curscodnr=212';

    // Create a stream
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header' => array(
                "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
                'Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1'
            )

        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

    echo $file;
```

I tried to change the character encoding to utf-8 but I always get a page with question marks instead of áéíóúãõç.

When I open the page directly in my browser it works just fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: Carreful, you have wrote your username and password; It's maybe not good for you or for the website ? And I've try your code (copy/past) and the encoding is ok

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'); echo $file;` to specified which encoding using to read `$file`.

Comment: @Xenofexs I wrote a temporary one, as soon as I get a solution I will change it back. But thanks :)

Comment: @Federico I tried it too, it doesn't work as well

Comment: I'm not really sure file_get_contents cares one way or another - it's just a byte stream for file_get_contents, right?  I suspect the problem is that when you view the results, you're not viewing in 8859-1.

Comment: @DanFarrell I tried running the script on the terminal, webpage and writing on my utf-8 encoded MySQL db. Neither gave me the correct encoding.

Comment: @JoãoMiranda, it works for me - have you tried to clear you cache? have you enabled the errors with `ini_set('display_errors', true);`?

Comment: I just cleared and still the same. Should I add it right before my code? If yes I just did it with no luck.

Comment: add `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true); ` at the very beginning of your code, and check if you see any warnings

Comment: You can say `Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1`. but there is no guarantee that the server will send you the data in that encoding.

Comment: @JoãoMiranda, if your database/browser/favorite viewer uses UTF8 by default, and you tell it to load a file, but you don't tell it that the file is in 8859-1, it will assume UTF-8 and you'll get funny glyphs.  I'm not hearing a verification that you're telling any of your viewers that your data is in 8859-1.

Comment: the fact that if I open the website directly I get the correct encoding doesn't imply that it should when I get it from `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: @DanFarrell How can I force them to know my encoding then?

Comment: @GolezTrol that's technically true, though the server really should respond with a 406 Not Acceptable in that case.  But I did go ahead and test the request, and got the response header 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' so it did comply with the request header.

Comment: So could you describe what again went wrong when you specified nothing or `charset=iso-8859-1`? You described what went wrong with UTF-8, which is obvious, but using the right charset it should work correctly.

Comment: By using `charset=iso-8859-1` I get characters like this when I display them: `Aten��o: neste relat�rio n�o aparecem as disciplinas`

Comment: @JoãoMiranda don't forget to change your test username and password.  They're still in the history of this question and still known by whoever grabbed it and whoever looks at the history.  And they still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like this might just be a problem of lost encoding details.

What you're describing is:

1. request document from webserver, specifying  encoding 8859-1
2. server responds with document in requested encoding, including header specifying the encoding *is* 8859-1.  This will look correct in a browser.
3. output document ( but not header data! ) from php ( where this goes isn't specified
4. open the data in some sort of viewer.

See where the encoding specification was lost, there in step 3?

The data can correctly be decoded with 8859-1, but only *will* be decoded with 8859-1 if the viewer is configured to use that encoding by default. Some apps may have a default of 8859-1, but UTF-8 is a lot more common these days.

If you load the data into a different storage engine, say mysql, the problem may compound.  mysql associates a charset with text data.  If your database defaults to utf-8, and you don't tell it the data is actually in 8859-1, but you don't tell it the data is in 8859-1, now you're feeding it data that is assumed to be in utf-8, and the data will be treated as such in the database going forward.  Now even if you ask the database for 8859-1 in the future, the data will be re-encoded from utf-8 to 8859-1, but it's not valid utf-8 - it's yet another *incorrect* set of bytes.

To address this problem, specify the encoding when you view the data, or when you save it to a database.

Comment: I had to change my mysql db to latin1 then it seems to have worked. Although not the ideal, it worked. So thanks!

Comment: IF you want to _store_ in utf8 you can set your _client_ charset to latin1 and then it will be conerted by mysql automatically